# How to have just one SAVE button for multiple text fields?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When there are multiple  text input fields on a page I'd like to have just one SAVE button for all of them that works only if all the fields have been informed.

```
<br>Legal Name (as listed with the IRS) <br>
<input type="text" autofocus id="LEGAL_name">
<button onclick="getText('LEGAL_name', 'Legal')">SAVE</button><br>

<br>Business name, if different <br
<input type="text" autofocus id="BUS_name">
<button onclick="getText('BUS_name', 'Bus')">SAVE</button><br>
```

Here there are only two input fields; on some pages of the application there may be as many as 8 or 10 fields.

Comment: You need to write Javascript code.

Comment: Use a traditional form submit?

Comment: I canz write that javascript code - `<button onclick="getText('BUS_name', 'Bus');getText('LEGAL_name', 'Legal')">SAVE</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to perform multiple operations against one button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("‪#‎Save‬").click(function(){//Button with id:Save
//perform your operations here
});
});
```